# Multiple groupings and groupby aggregations using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that looks very similar to the data below.

1. I would like to create two groups using values in the sku column.

   group1 - new    &

   group2 - old
2. Within the group1 - new, I would like to then groupby rack and take the average of each grouped rack and sum everything in the group1 - old

data:

```
     rack   sku    used    free     total   date
     a      old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
     b      old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
     c      old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
     d      new     2       1       3       11/1/2020
     e      new     2       1       3       11/1/2020
     f      old     1       1       2       11/1/2020
     g      old     1       1       2       11/1/2020
     e      new     2       2       4       11/1/2020
     d      new     2       2       4       11/1/2020
```

**Desired Result**

```
        used    free    total   date

        2       1.5     3.5     11/1/2020
        2       1.5     3.5     11/1/2020
        5       14      19      11/1/2020
```

***We get this result above because*** :

group1- new has two groups: ***d*** and ***e***
The average for d used is 2, the average for d free is 1.5 and the average for d total is 3.5

The average for e used is 2, the average for e free is 1.5 and the average for e total is 3.5

group2- old is simply taking the sum
which the used is 5, free is 14 and total is 19.

This is what the data looks like after the grouping:

```
id  group   used    free    total   date
d   new     2       1       3       11/1/2020
d   new     2       2       4       11/1/2020
e   new     2       1       3       11/1/2020
e   new     2       2       4       11/1/2020
a   old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
b   old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
c   old     1       4       5       11/1/2020
f   old     1       1       2       11/1/2020
g   old     1       1       2       11/1/2020
```

This is what I am doing:

```
    new = df[df.sku.str.contains('|'.df(['new']), na = False)]

    old = df[df.sku.str.contains('|'.df(['old']), na = False)] 

set = jdf.groupby('rack').agg({'used': 'mean', 'free': 'mean', 
                                           'total': 'mean'}).sum().to_frame().T
```

I am just not sure how to put this together to create the new dataframe.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Hi I updated the post.  group1 new should be grouped by rack and then average should be taken for all 3 columns (used, free, total)

Comment: How is processing `date` ?

Comment: I wonder could date be included?

Comment: hmm, is possible use `.groupby(['rack', 'date'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by conditions with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for match multiple `sku` and for old all not match values by `~` for invert mask:

```
mask = df.sku.isin(['new','foo','foo1','foo3'])
new = df[mask]

old = df[~mask]
```

Then aggregate `mean` and for all another values use `sum` only for numeric columns:

```
df = (new.groupby('rack').mean()
         .append(old.select_dtypes(np.number).sum().to_frame('old').T)
         .rename_axis('col')
         .reset_index())

print (df)
   col  backup  free  total
0    d     2.0   1.5    3.5
1    e     2.0   1.5    3.5
2  old     5.0  14.0   19.0
```

If possible grouping by `rack` and `date` solution is a bit changed - for old values is used first `date` value:

```
mask = df.sku.isin(['new','foo','foo1','foo3'])
new = df[mask]

old = df[~mask] 

df = (new.groupby(['rack', 'date']).mean()
         .append(old.select_dtypes(np.number).sum().to_frame(('old', old['date'].iat[0])).T)
         .reset_index())

print (df)
  rack       date  backup  free  total
0    d  11/1/2020     2.0   1.5    3.5
1    e  11/1/2020     2.0   1.5    3.5
2  old  11/1/2020     5.0  14.0   19.0
```

Comment: ok thank you @jezrael - I am wondering if I can exclude the d, e, old column?

Comment: @Lynnette - sure, add `.rename_axis('col').reset_index()`

Comment: Hi @jezrael, what if I have to filter multiple strings, not just 'new' - could I do:  mask = df.sku == 'new', 'foo', 'foo1', 'foo3'  ??

Comment: @Lynnette - Use `mask = df.sku.isin(['new','foo','foo1','foo3'])`

Comment: ok thank you much for your assistance- I will try this now

Comment: may I use this if the col CONTAINS : df.sku.str.contains(['new','foo', 'foo1', 'foo4'])????

Comment: @Lynnette - it testing substrings, so need `df.sku.str.contains('|'.join(['new','foo', 'foo1', 'foo4']))`

Comment: @Lynnette - If not substrings like `new1`, `new2`, `foo569` then test by `isin` working well

Comment: Hi @jezrael it is saying: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values   could I use isna??

Comment: @Lynnette - then `df.sku.str.contains('|'.join(['new','foo', 'foo1', 'foo4']), na=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You can first `groupby` by `'sku'`. Then you can get a target group with `get_group`, `groupby` again and calculate the summary. For example, mean value for `'new'`:

```
g = df.groupby('sku')
g.get_group('new').groupby('rack').mean()
```

Output:

```
      used  free  total
rack                   
d      2.0   1.5    3.5
e      2.0   1.5    3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach to take the mean by rack to all groups except the last one (which will be the sum):

```py
# Define last group for suming
last_grp = 'old'
# Calculate the mean by rack to all groups but last one
out = df.query('sku!=@last_grp').groupby(['sku','rack']).mean()
# Add sum from last group to df
out.loc[(last_grp, ''),:] = df.query('sku==@last_grp').select_dtypes(np.number).sum()
# Add date back to df (if more than one date, it'll be concatenated with comma)
out['date'] = ','.join(df.date.unique())
```

Output:

```
          used  free  total       date
sku rack                              
new d      2.0   1.5    3.5  11/1/2020
    e      2.0   1.5    3.5  11/1/2020
old        5.0  14.0   19.0  11/1/2020
```

Note: If you don't want to summarize all groups, you gonna need to replace `df.query('sku!=@last_grp')` by `df[df.sku.isin(target_grps)]` where `target_grps` stands by your target groups (e.g. 'new', 'foo', 'foo2').

Comment: Hi @Caina , what if I have multiple strings to filter - say 'new' , 'foo1', 'foo2' ?

Comment: Probably you're gonna need to loop through the groups (except the last one, that you want to take the sum), and concatenate them.

Comment: Hi @Lynnette, it seems you already have a very good answer. I'm writing this comment just to notice that I've updated the answer with a scalable approach as well. Best!